# Generic as parameter to constructor

Tags: generics, kotlin

I'm looking at a code that has several entries like this:

```
open class PersonFinder: Finder<Long, Person>(Person::class.java)
open class CompanyFinder: Finder<Long, Company>(Company::class.java)
open class DeviceFinder: Finder<Long, Device>(Device::class.java)
```

I'd like a more generic approach, something like this:

```
open class GenericFinder<T>: Finder<Long, T>(T::class.java)
```

but the syntax is invalid as T::class.java cannot be used as a paramater there. Is there any way I can make this work in a idiomatic way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution:

```
open class GenericFinder<T>(type: Class<T>) : Finder<Long, T>(type)
```

Comment: Is there a reason for `type` to be nullable?

Answer (score 0):

If you (at least reasonably often) want to use `GenericFinder` directly instead of subclassing it, you can add a helper function with a [`reified` type parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters):

```
open class GenericFinder<T>(type: Class<T>) : Finder<Long, T>(type) { ... }

inline fun <reified T> GenericFinder() = GenericFinder(T::class.java)
```

Comment: That's nice. But the reason for the subclassing is that it allows me to do something like this: "val person = Person.byId(1)" instead of "val person = GenericFinder(Person::class.java).byId(1)" because the GenericFinder is a companion object of Person in this case.

Comment: With this, you can write `val Person = GenericFinder<Person>()` and then you have `val person = Person.byId(1)` as desired.